# Instagram Photo Effects in Windows 8 metro apps using c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, colors, microsoft-metro, direct2d

I need to implement Instagram photo effects like amaro, hudson, sepia, rise, and so on. I know this article only use basic effects: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Metro-Style-lightweight-24589f50

Another way suggested by people are to implement Direct2d and then apply using that. But for that I would need to write C++ code, where I have zero experience.

Can anyone suggest some other way to implement Instagram effects in c#?

Is there any built in c++ file for these effects?

Answer (score 1):

Please see this example from CodeProject : [Metro Style Lightweight Image Processing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/340859/Metro-Style-Lightweight-Image-Processing)

The above example contains these image effects.

- Negative
- Color filter
- Emboss
- SunLight
- Black & White
- Brightness
- Oilpaint
- Tint

Please note above example seems to be implemented on either developer preview or release preview of Windows 8. So you will get error like this

> 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap' does not contain a
>   constructor that takes 1 arguments

So you have to create instance of `WriteableBitmap` by passing pixel height and pixel width of image. I have edited the sample and it is working for me. You have to change `wb = new WriteableBitmap(bs);` to `wb = await GetWB();`

```
StorageFile originalImageFile;
WriteableBitmap cropBmp;
public async Task<WriteableBitmap> GetWB()
{
    if (originalImageFile != null)
    {
        //originalImageFile is the image either loaded from file or captured image.
        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await originalImageFile.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(stream);
            BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
            byte[] pixels = await GetPixelData(decoder, Convert.ToUInt32(bmp.PixelWidth), Convert.ToUInt32(bmp.PixelHeight));
            cropBmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight);
            Stream pixStream = cropBmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
            pixStream.Write(pixels, 0, (int)(bmp.PixelWidth * bmp.PixelHeight * 4));
        } 
    }
    return cropBmp;
}
```

Let me know if you are facing any problem.